# Unkown meta_value in ACF

Tags: database, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF, but I wonder the meta_value means?

Below is a snippet from my database:

```
meta_id post_id meta_key    meta_value
9394    4661    _carousel_0_image   field_5683f27fd880e
```

So what exactly is `field_5683f27fd880e`? 
Is the `5683f27fd880e` an serialized or hashed value or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every meta value saved there is a second row prefixed with `_` that stores what field definition this value refers to. Do not delete it.

Your example additionally is a repeater which makes it more complex but the docs has a nice explanation:

> $ParentName_$RowNumber_$ChildName

So you have a repeater field called `carousel` which has a subfield called `image` and this is the first row:

```
carousel_0_image
```

As said an additional row called `_carousel_0_image` is saved by ACF to know which field this relates to. It is (if I remember correctly) some index relating to  a Custom Post Type that stores ACFs Field definitions.

As a closing note: ACF has [support](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/) and third party questions usually get closed here as off-topic, I am just responding because I knew this off the top of my head.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks a lot for the information.